# Changing EC2 Cassandra instance's remote access port?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

I set up Cassandra on EC2 according to this: http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise2.2/install/install_dse_ami

All is well, and it's all up and running, including OpsCenter.  For the time being, I have a completely open (0.0.0.0/0) security policy.  I'll fiddle with that once I can finally connect remotely.

The problem, I'm told, is that our corporate firewall blocks almost all ports, save for 22, 80, 8080, and 8888.  Thus, when I try to connect to Cassandra locally: `e:\cassandra\bin\cassandra-cli -host ec2-X-X-X-X.us-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com -port 9160`

I get the error: 
`org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

Given that I cant open any additional ports in my corporate firewall, what can I do to connect to Cassandra?  Can I tell it to allow connections on 8080 instead?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are having trouble connecting from your machine to the Cassandra machine due to the corporate firewall. There are a couple of solutions

1. Connect to machine via ssh first

   You could connect to the EC2 machine and connect from there.
2. Change the thrift port

You certainly could change the thrift port in the cassandra.yaml file, but make sure you change it in the opscenterd.conf also.  Realize that if something else is running on 8080, then this probably will not work.

You could also look into using the [DataStax DevCenter](http://www.datastax.com/2013/08/introducing-datastax-devcenter) too, which would help keep things behind the firewall.  This is in alpha, but it may help your situation.